# Why does this regex not work on linux?

Tags: linux, find, regex

I can't say it works on Windows but from my understanding this regex is correct and how I would write it (except maybe the `^` at the beginning)

*From http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/showpost.php?p=382944&postcount=3*

```
^.+\.((jpg)|(gif)|(exe))$
```

When I run

```
find -regex '^.+\.((jpg)|(gif)|(exe))$'
```

my exe does not show up when i write

```
find -regex '^.+\.exe$'
```

It does. Why doesnt `find -regex` want to use `()` or `(()|())?` I always thought that was valid for everything.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GNU find by default uses emacs regular expressions, you can change that type with `-regextype` option (see man find).

If you use `-regextype posix-egrep` your expression seems to work.  You could then also probably reduce the pattern to `^.+(jpg|gif|exe)$`

With emacs: `find .  -regex  '.+\(jpg\|gif\|exe\)$'` . See [this section of emacs manual](http://jamesthornton.com/emacs/node/emacs_97.html) for those specific regex rules.  You need to escape `|` and `()` for them not to be literal.

Answer (score 3):

In emacs regexps `(`, `|` and `)` are literal **unless** escaped, this is exactly the opposite of all other regular expression formats.

Your expression works as `^.+\.\(jpg\|exe\|gif\)$`.